# ValueError: text input must of type `str` (single example)

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am trying to run the evaluation of both MCLIP and ItalianCLIP on zero-shot learning task found this notebook [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zfWeVWY79XXH63Ci-pk8xxx3Vu_RRgW-?usp=sharing). when running the below prediction cell I get the below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py in encode(self, sentences, batch_size, show_progress_bar, output_value, convert_to_numpy, convert_to_tensor, device, normalize_embeddings)
    159         for start_index in trange(0, len(sentences), batch_size, desc="Batches", disable=not show_progress_bar):
    160             sentences_batch = sentences_sorted[start_index:start_index+batch_size]
--> 161             features = self.tokenize(sentences_batch)
    162             features = batch_to_device(features, device)
    163 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py in tokenize(self, texts)
    317         Tokenizes the texts
    318         """
--> 319         return self._first_module().tokenize(texts)
    320 
    321     def get_sentence_features(self, *features):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentence_transformers/models/CLIPModel.py in tokenize(self, texts)
     69             images = None
     70 
---> 71         inputs = self.processor(text=texts_values, images=images, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
     72         inputs['image_text_info'] = image_text_info
     73         return inputs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/processing_clip.py in __call__(self, text, images, return_tensors, **kwargs)
     97 
     98         if text is not None:
---> 99             encoding = self.tokenizer(text, return_tensors=return_tensors, **kwargs)
    100 
    101         if images is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in __call__(self, text, text_pair, text_target, text_pair_target, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   2521             if not self._in_target_context_manager:
   2522                 self._switch_to_input_mode()
-> 2523             encodings = self._call_one(text=text, text_pair=text_pair, **all_kwargs)
   2524         if text_target is not None:
   2525             self._switch_to_target_mode()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in _call_one(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   2580         if not _is_valid_text_input(text):
   2581             raise ValueError(
-> 2582                 "text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) "
   2583                 "or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples)."
   2584             )

ValueError: text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Question is what is sentences_batch what does it actually contain if you print it? Just maybe it could also be an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `.tolist()`

This is what I mean:

```
preds, modeling_outputs = model.predict(x_test.values);
```

The code above generated the error message:

> text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).

But after adding `.tolist()` as seen below, it fixed the error message:

```
preds, modeling_outputs = model.predict(x_test.values.tolist());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue while using finbert but when I read the error carefully I understood what’s the issue… The error itself is telling what it’s expecting i.e string and it is getting stuck because it is not finding string or list[list(str)] so if you’re applying the function on an excel column just add .dropna() at the end while reading the excel sheet which will drop all empty cells and make sure none of your rows in the column have only ‘integers’ and not string so that will again throw error so just convert your numbers to string before proceeding. This worked for me. I spent more than a week behind this only to realise in the end how small of an error it was. Felt like an idiot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).